# Can I use Power Query to extract data into different tabs?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have several spreadsheets I would like to combine into one and have each sheet on a separate tab. Is there a solution in Excel that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use Power Query.

In the top in Excel goto Data and select within Get & Transform for From table in your case New Query > From File. Then select your data range or file you want to combine. Do this for every sheet or file.

The sheets or files are loaded as tables in PowerQuery. Then use the append queries in the top in PowerQuery to combine the tables.

You can also load every query on a sheet in your destination file

Comment: How do I load the query to different sheets then? is that in the query view?

Comment: Sorry I did not check it for a while. Yes, in the query editor, you can do a right click on the query > Load to.